# whoami: bad uid 0 / Magisk vs. Toybox

Tags: root-access, magisk, toybox, symlink

I replaced old `/system/bin/toybox` with a new binary from http://landley.net/toybox/bin then I created symlinks with `for i in $(./toybox); do ln -s toybox $i`. There is `su` in symlinks.

Now I cannot open Magisk anymore, stuck at splash screen mask.
Also MiXplorer cannot browse root dirs.
With Terminal Emulator I can still browse root dirs.

If I type `which su` I get `/sbin/su` which is a symlink to `/sbin/magisk`.
I have not yet tried to reboot because I fear to get stuck, maybe it would repair by itself but who knows?
If I type `whoami` I get `bad uid 0`, after `su shell` I get `bad uid 2000` and so on.

How can I restore root? I can access TWRP recovery.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4547123

Answer (score 2):

Turned out new toybox has not all applets Android requires. Had to reboot into TWRP, restore original toybox and delete my symlinks, otherwise Magisk would complain about another `su`.

Thanks @alecxs for his hints and quick support